# DDOS Mitigation Services

Tags: security, web-server, ddos, denial-of-service

Over the past week we have been a victim of two seperate ddos attacks varying in scale.  The last one was very large and very hard to mitigate.  We are looking at solutions from veriSign and Akamai but the prices are so steep.  I found a company called BlockDOS.net and their prices are much more reasonable but I've never heard of them and can't find much information about them.  Before I trust our e-commerce website to a comapny like this I typically like to have more info.  Does anyone have experience with BlockDOS.net or can anyone recommend another provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with [BlackLotus.net](http://www.blacklotus.net/) and [Gigenet.com](http://www.gigenet.com/) on several occasions during denial of service attacks and both were a pleasure to work with. Both offer proxy type solutions that allow you to host else where and they have their own hosting products and offer both dedicated and virtual servers.

Mitigating attacks is never cheap but in my experience these providers are much cheaper than the larger providers. Their total filtering capacity might be much smaller than Akamai but typically it's enough to do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that Black Lotus offered a web proxy solution.  I knew they offered appliances.  thanks for your input.